# App Transport Security issue

Tags: ios, xcode7

I'm running xcode 7.2 with latest iOS SDK (9.2). The Apple document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) regarding to the options which will enable http request to be allowed by ATS on specific domain no longer work.

Please see attached images:

[image: app.plist settings]

[image: Request to my site is still blocked]

Even though I disable ATS by delete `Exception Domains` key & set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES`. The request still be blocked!?

Any idea?

Comment: @MayankPatel Doesn't work too.

Comment: set Yes for Allow arbitrary loads

Comment: @MayankPatel I don't want to allow unsecure requests globally. But even I did this, the request still be blocked.

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the right `http` URL in exception domain? I am curious as `tritome.info` doesn't look like a proper base url.

Comment: @Gandalf Yes, the request url is: http://tritome.info/upload.php. The domain is a virtual domain & it is already work if I browse to it by browser.

Answer (score 2):

just add these lines in your .plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
     </dict>
```

Answer (score -1):

[From Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)

In iOS9, ATS enforces best practices during network calls, including the use of HTTPS.

> ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt. You should adopt ATS as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an existing one. If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible.

```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
   <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
   <dict>
      <key>tritome.info</key>
      <dict>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>1.0</string>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
          <false/>
       </dict>
    </dict>
 </dict>
```

---

Hope it works!

Comment: I don't think your domain key value is a valid one.

Comment: I did all of these & it didn't help.

Comment: i think issue is with your domain make sure your domain is working .. you can read apple doc..