# iOS Afnetworking: Request failed unauthorized (401)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using afnetworking. And getting error unauthorised 401 on POST request.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    //[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth"];
   //[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    //[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Bearer \(token!)" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    //sessionManager.requestSerializer.setValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
         NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        }
     }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);

     }];
```

Comment: Is your app working fine with mobile data ?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I am calling a site (SSL) from a library routine, which works in it's own workspace with a test app, however, once I try to use the library in a different app, I get "Request failed: unauthorized (401)".

I have tried all of the TLS exception parameters to rule that out, especially the forward secrecy bypass as I'm not sure our cert supports Forward Secrecy.  Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by dumping AFNetworking and used NSUrlSession instead

Comment: I also dumped AFNetworking and used URLSession instead

Answer (score 0):

In your .plist , have you added following lines?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
     </dict>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946791/app-transport-security-issue/34947223#34947223 check this

Answer (score 0):

Make it use these, this code will work fine:

```
[request setValue:[dict valueForKey:@"Authorization"] 

forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

sample code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest  *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Authorization"]);

[request setValue:[dict valueForKey:@"Authorization"] 

forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

//NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer =[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)

{
success(responseObject);

} 

failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

id object = [NSJSONSerialization              JSONObjectWithData:error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponse DataErrorKey] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


NSLog(@"%@",object);

failure(error);

}];

 [operation start];
```

Comment: Nsdictionary *dict

Comment: can you please tell me what dict? from where this **dict** is getting the data?

Comment: [request setValue:place_key_here

forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"]   Check your endpoins. they provide Authorization or key